# Tiling in groupby on dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, tiling, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that contains returns, size and sedols for a couple of dates.

My goal is to identify the top and bottom values for a certain condition per date, i.e I want the top decile largest size entries and the bottom decile smallest size entries for each date and flag them in a new column by 'xx' and 'yy'.

I am confused how to apply the tiling while grouping as well as creating a new column, here is what I already have.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

def create_dummy_data(start_date, days, entries_pday):
    date_sequence_lst = [dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') + 
dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,days)]
    date_sequence_lst = date_sequence_lst * entries_pday                
    returns_lst = [round(np.random.uniform(low=-0.10,high=0.20),2) for _ in range(entries_pday*days)]

    size_lst = [round(np.random.uniform(low=10.00,high=10000.00),0) for _ in range(entries_pday*days)]

    rdm_sedol_lst = [(''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(7))) for x in range(entries_pday)] 
    rdm_sedol_lst = rdm_sedol_lst * days

    dates_returns_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':date_sequence_lst , 'Sedols':rdm_sedol_lst, 'Returns':returns_lst,'Size':size_lst})
    dates_returns_df = dates_returns_df.sort_values('Date',ascending=True)
    dates_returns_df = dates_returns_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    return dates_returns_df


def order_df_by(df_in,column_name):
    df_out = df_in.sort_values(['Date',column_name],ascending=[True,False])
    return df_out


def get_ntile(df_in,ntile):
    df_in['Tiled'] = df_in.groupby(['Date'])['Size'].transform(lambda x : pd.qcut(x,ntile))
    return df_in

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create dummy returns
    data_df = create_dummy_data('2001-01-01',31,10)
    # sort by attribute
    data_sorted_df = order_df_by(data_df,'Size')
    #ntile data per date
    data_ntiled = get_ntile(data_sorted_df, 10)

    for key, item in data_ntiled:
        print(data_ntiled.get_group(key))
```

so far I would be expecting deciled results based on 'Size' for each date, the next step would be to filter only for decile 1 and decile 10 and flag the entries 'xx' and 'yy' respectively.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `transform` on the [pandas.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) method with labels 1 through ntile+1 for a *decile* column, then conditionally set *flag* with `np.where` using decile values:

```
...
def get_ntile(df_in, ntile):
    df_in['Tiled'] = df_in.groupby(['Date'])['Size'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, ntile, labels=list(range(1, ntile+1))))
    return df_in

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create dummy returns
    data_df = create_dummy_data('2001-01-01',31,10)
    # sort by attribute
    data_sorted_df = order_df_by(data_df,'Size')
    #ntile data per date
    data_ntiled = get_ntile(data_sorted_df, 10)

    data_ntiled['flag'] = np.where(data_ntiled['Tiled']==1.0, 'YY',
                                   np.where(data_ntiled['Tiled']==10.0, 'XX', np.nan))

    print(data_ntiled.reset_index(drop=True).head(15))

#          Date  Returns   Sedols    Size   Tiled flag
# 0  2001-01-01    -0.03  TEEADVJ  8942.0    10.0   XX
# 1  2001-01-01    -0.03  PDBWGBJ  7142.0     9.0  nan
# 2  2001-01-01     0.03  QNVVPIC  6995.0     8.0  nan
# 3  2001-01-01     0.04  NTKEAKB  6871.0     7.0  nan
# 4  2001-01-01     0.20  ZVVCLSJ  6541.0     6.0  nan
# 5  2001-01-01     0.12  IJKXLIF  5131.0     5.0  nan
# 6  2001-01-01     0.14  HVPDRIU  4490.0     4.0  nan
# 7  2001-01-01    -0.08  XNOGFET  3397.0     3.0  nan
# 8  2001-01-01    -0.06  JOARYWC  2582.0     2.0  nan
# 9  2001-01-01     0.12  FVKBQGU   723.0     1.0   YY
# 10 2001-01-02     0.03  ZVVCLSJ  9291.0    10.0   XX
# 11 2001-01-02     0.14  HVPDRIU  8875.0     9.0  nan
# 12 2001-01-02     0.08  PDBWGBJ  7496.0     8.0  nan
# 13 2001-01-02     0.02  FVKBQGU  7307.0     7.0  nan
# 14 2001-01-02    -0.01  QNVVPIC  7159.0     6.0  nan
```